# Maximum frequency of a passive RC/RL band pass filter

Tags: passive-filter

I'm planning an application for signal strength measurement in a wide band of frequencies (around 800(0)-10000Mhz). The way I want to implement it is by making a series of band pass filters with a step of ~1Ghz and then analysing each range separately.

So some core points are:

1. Each band pass filter should be able to operate at a multi-GHz frequency and make a more or less meaningful filtering (I'm not going to launch rockets ;) )
2. Frequency response steepness does not really matter, each range may be overlapping it's neighbors. If filtering can be performed with 2/4-order filter it's fine

I already spend couple of days researching and here are some results (or their absence):

1. I couldn't find any maximum values which can be obtained using "regular" RC/RL filters, I'm not a radio-engineer so for me it would be pretty hard to design any advanced filtering application
2. From what I found, regular ceramic capacitors is not the best option for such frequencies, a better option could be mica capacitors
3. For resistors I guess the same story - use HF versions
4. Better use capacitors (RC) instead of inductors (LC), since it's easier to predict/calculate the values we need
5. Premade solutions on the market are usually designed for very specific frequencies
6. There are some tunable filters, but they are quite expensive and do not cover all the frequencies I'm interested in

So, is it even possible to design a "real" high frequency filter using a "regular" n-order RC/RL approach, assuming that we will be using a high frequency resistors / capacitors? Or maybe you know or can suggest some alternatives?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry if I formulated the question uncrealy. What I'm trying to understand is the possibility of building RC or RL band pass filter which would work on multi-GHz frequency (and which one would work better), or maybe it's not possible using passive components

Comment: You’ve ruled out inductors, yes? Have you a reason?